# How to update properties via bicep for existing resource

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I am trying to update the public multiple ip of existing azure firewall  deployed using arm with bicep code.

```
resource firewall 'Microsoft.Network/azureFirewalls@2021-05-01' existing = {
  name: firewallName
  location: location
  properties: {
    ipConfigurations: azureFirewallIpConfigurations
  }
  dependsOn: [
    publicIPAddress
  ]
}
```

I see that we cannot use properties on existing resources

Do we have a better way to do this via the bicep code to we need to do this via azcli /powershell ?

Comment: `existing` is just a keyword to **reference** resource. if you want to update the resource dont use the keyword existing.

Comment: @Thomas will it not remove all the existing config mentioned in there ?

Comment: You would need to recreate a full bicep file with everything from your existing ARM. if you just need to update some property Az cli or powershell maybe better suited as you said.

Comment: I wouldn't use `cli` or`powershell` for this. If you run the original BiCep main it will overwrite any changes applied outside of the main file. You should do as Thomas has said and recreate the full BiCep file. If you export the ARM template from the portal - you can use `az bicep decompile -f .\pathtoexportarmfile` to create the biCep file

Answer (score 0):

Bicep is idempotent so if you do not specify `existing` and instead do
`resource firewall 'Microsoft.Network/azureFirewalls@2021-05-01' = {`, it will only create the resource if it does not exist and it will only modify the resource if it has any changes to make.

A great way to see how this works is to make use of `what-if` with a tutorial found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deploy-what-if?tabs=azure-powershell%2CCLI). This will allow you to see if it will make any changes and what exactly those changes are if any.